# How to update array of objects with same value in reference_id (FK Column) in Sequelize JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sql-update, sequelize.js

I have an array of objects which somewhat looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: '5b29c08b-597c-460c-a3c7-ac8852b7a5dc',
    option_text: 'njnj',
    answer: false
  },
  {
    id: '8ff5bda6-9335-495c-9c72-15ef258b899b',
    option_text: 'jnjn',
    answer: true
  }
]
```

Here the `answer` column is inter-related like if any of the object's `answer` is set to `true` the other will come as `false` from frontend. So I've to update all the row associated with the referenced id.
What problem am facing is that the update query is not running but it is going inside the `then` block of the code instead of throwing error. Below is my code for the same:

```
// UPDATE Option
exports.updateOption = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.Option.update(req.body, {
      where: { question_id: req.params.id }
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('A');
      return res.status(200).send(errors.UPDATED_SUCESSFULLY);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('B');
      return res.status(204).send(errors.INTERNAL_SERVER);    
    });
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('C');
    return res.status(204).send(errors.INTERNAL_SERVER);
  }
};
```

Sample Table Data for the same:
[image: data]

What I am thinking is that firstly to `answer` column `false` for all the rows associated with the same `question_id` and then update the particular row which has `answer` set to `true`.
But is this a good approach or anyone can suggest me some better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute all updates in the same transaction (to avoid inconsistencies in DB):

```
sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
  const options = req.body;
  for (const option of options) {
    await db.Option.update(option, {
        where: { question_id: req.params.id },
         transaction
      });
  }
}).then(...
```